# Add comments to delta

Tags: mysql, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

If a pyspark dataframe is reading some data from a table and writing it to azure delta lake
Can we add comments to this newly written file?
For e.g

```
Df = sql("select * from table1(doing some manipulation on this table data)")

Df.write.mode('overwrite').format('delta') \
  .option('overwriteschema',"true").save(newfolder)
```

Comment: hi @Richi, if you want to add a comment on SQL use `--`, python  `#` and scala `//`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set comment on the table, you can use [COMMENT ON TABLE](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-comment.html) SQL command:

```py
spark.sql(f"COMMENT ON TABLE delta.`{newfolder}` IS 'my comment'")
```

Notice, that we use special syntax to refer to a Delta table by path:

```
delta.`path`
```

If you want to set comment on a specific column, you can use [ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-table.html) SQL command:

```py
col_name = "abc"
spark.sql(f"ALTER TABLE delta.`{newfolder}` ALTER COLUMN {col_name} COMMENT 'my comment'")
```